# Can not make static reference to non static method?

Tags: java, static-methods, instance-methods

So, in short. I have two classes.

```
package rpg;

public class Engine {
    public void main(String args[]) {
        Start.gameStart();
        System.out.println(menuResult);
    }
}
```

and

```
package rpg;
public class Start {
    int menuResult = 3;
    public int gameStart() 
    {
        return menuResult;
    }
    public int getMenuResult()
    {
        return Start.menuResult;
    }
}
```

It keeps throwing up the error 'Cannot make static reference to non-static method gameStart()'.
I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't find it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create instance of `Start` class and call `gameStart()` method on that instance because `gameStart()` is instance method not static method.

```
 public void main(String args[]) {
       new Start().gameStart();
       ..................
  }
```

Only static methods can be accessed by using class name as perfix.

Comment: So... what exactly is `new Start().gameStart();` doing? It seems like it's creating an object, but how would I call it?

Comment: You are creating an instance (object) for Start() class and calling gameStart() method of that instance (remember gameStart() is instance method).

Comment: It creates a new object and then it calls method gameStart() on this object.

Answer (score 3):

```
public int gameStart() <--- Instance method not static method
```

call it on instance

```
 Start start = new Start();
 start.gameStart();
```

So finally your classes should look like below

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Start start = new Start();
    start.gameStart();
    System.out.println(start.getMenuResult());
}

public class Start {
   private int menuResult = 3;
    public int gameStart() {
        return this.menuResult;//Don't know why there are two methods
    }
    public int getMenuResult() {
        return this.menuResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Notice that, if `gameStart()` were made static, that would just the first domino stone to fall down, followed by the rest of the whole `Start` class. Clearly not OP's intention.

Comment: Clearly forgot to add make `menuResult` also static. Thanks.

Comment: ... then followed by making `getMenuResult` static as well :)

Answer (score 2):

first of all the main method should be

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

}
```

I assume you can have multiple games, and hence you should be able to start multiple instances so you should create a non static class that can be created and then actions performed against.

to answer your original question, you need to have a static variable that have static getters and setters..

```
public class Start {
    private static int menuResult = 3;
    public static int gameStart() 
    {
        return menuResult;
    }
    public static int getMenuResult()
    {
        return Start.menuResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the method to be static, just add the keyword static in the function definition. That would get rid of the error. But if you want to keep the class Start the way it is, then you should create an instance of Start in the main function and then call the method. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to invoke a method on its class name. you should be creating a new object and invoke its method

```
public void main(String args[]) {
        new Start().gameStart();
        System.out.println(menuResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Start.gameStart()` refers to a method which would be `public static int gameStart()` because Start is the class and not an instance of the object.

If you declare a method on an object, you need to apply it to instance of the object and not its class.

When to use static or instanciated methods ?

- instanciated : whenever you need to apply the method to the object you're in. example : `mycake.cook();`
- static : when the actions you do inside your method have nothing to do with an object in particular. example : `Cake.throwThemAll();`

mycake is an instance of a Cake, declared this way : `Cake mycake = new Cake();`

Cake is the class representing the object.

You should, i guess, have a read at some object oriented programmation course if you still have a doubt about objects, classes and instances.

Answer (score 0):

While Other answers are Correct , that remains the Question that Why you Can't access Instance 
method Directly from Class name , In Java all static (methods , fields) bind with Class Name and when Class Is Loading to the Memory (Stack) all static members are Loading to the Stack , and this time Instance Method is not visible to Class. instance Method will Load into Heap portion in the memory and can only be access by Object references  .